# ASP.NET UpdatePanel dosn't work with Response.Write in Page_Load

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have that example:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>UpdatePanel</legend>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Panel created."></asp:Label><br />
            </fieldset>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" /></div>
```

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // doesn work with:
    Response.Write("eg.");    
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "Refreshed at " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

This works fine. When I click in the `Button` the `Label` updates without refreshing the page, but if I have `Response.Write` in the `Page_Load` event, when I click the button the `UpdatePanel` doesn't work, and I need the `Page_Load`.

How I can solve my problem? Thanks.

Comment: What isnt working is if i have code in Page_Load the Button1_Click dont work, becouse is connected with the UpdatePanel

Comment: Even in an asynchronous postback the page runs through the whole [lifecycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx) including the `Load` stage.

Comment: The code that isnt working is the Button1_Click event.

Comment: @youarebannedfromStackoverf: _what_ code in `Page_Load` causes the button-click event to not trigger?

Comment: Any code, if I have for example: `Response.Write("eg.");`  The UpdatePanel and the buttons connect to them doesnt work.

Comment: @youarebannedfromStackoverf It's a little bit baffling why you're refusing to show the code that doesn't work.

Comment: As I said this is an example, when I solve the problem I'll use the UpdatePanel in my project. But right now in my Page_Load i just have `Response.Write("eg.");`

Comment: @youarebannedfromStackoverf: with `Response.Write` you have shown a bad example since that   could indeed cause issues with the UpdatePanel. What is the actual code that causes the issue?

Comment: Oh sorry for the time wasted, yes the problem is the `Response.Write()`. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `Response.Write()` in your `Page_Load` function, as it will break the `UpdatePanel`.

In fact, using `Response.Write()` is often a bad idea, because you don't control where in the DOM the written content will end up. Instead, if you need some simple debug output, then use other means such as `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()`. Or if you need to add something to the DOM, add a control such as `Label` and manipulate that.

Comment: Problem solved, thanks for your time and for all who tried to help me.